# How to have predefined categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my users to be able to select from predefined values of categories. I took a look at other Stackoverflow questions but didn't get them fully. Here is my code right now....

I have my Categories model and Users create prices (which is another name for Items).

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :prices

    def name
        "#{category}"
    end
end
```

My prices belong to categories. note: The prices table has a category_id.

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :date, :price

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Here is how the form and view look as of now:

Form

```
<%= form_for(@price) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true  %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

View

```
<p><b>User:</b><%= @price.user_id %></p>  
<p><b>Date:</b><%= @price.date %> </p>
<p><b>Name:</b><%= @price.price_name %></p>
<p><b>Price:</b><%= number_to_currency(@price.price) %></p>
<p><b>Category:</b><%= @price.category.name %></p>
```

**How do i create the categories i want in the drop down menu?**

Thank you I'm a very appreciative!

Comment: Why can't you put the categories in the categories table?

Comment: Also, but I'm just asking; why should a Price have a category? Shouldn't a product have a category and a price?

Comment: You mean have their own columns like , toys:string?

Comment: Users actually create Prices, or in other words Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the `collection_select` form helper method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

It will look something like this:

```
<div class="category">
  <%= f.label :category %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

Then in the view:

```
<p><b>Category:</b><%= @price.category.name %></p>
```

This assumes that your `categories` table has a `name` field which stores the category names.

Comment: @David, How do i populate the database to have a permanent categories like Games, Entertainment, Foods,etc?

Comment: @David <%= @price.category.name %> gives me the error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass in my Prices#show.

Comment: @JustinRoR: That means that `@price.category` is `nil`, which means that the model's `category_id` field is `NULL` in the database.  You'll have to assign a category to the price model.  You should be able to do that by selecting one from the drop-down created by the `collection_select` method.  (If you don't select a category when filling out the form, the category will be `nil` and you will get that error.)

Comment: @JustinRoR: As far as pre-populating the database with permanent categories, look at @denisjacquemin's answer and check out the screencast that he links to.

Answer (score 2):

you can create your data in db/seeds.rb

`rake db:seed` to load them (Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data for more details

Comment: Is there another way, like putting it in the model instead just in case i screw up in the future?

Comment: @JustinRoR well, I suggest you to keep the seeds.rb solution as it is the cleaner way to do it as far as I know. What do you mean by "just in case i screw up in the future"?

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible, as i haven't created an application before or put it online but if i was to rake db:migrate:reset during production mode, it would get rid of the categories and may cause problems because i have to re-run the db:seed instead of it just automatically being in the model or table, that's the scenario i thought of. I am a beginner, but i am still going to do as you said, thank you.